# Restore file drag and drop

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I want to block file drag and drop on an application. For this, I can use win32 API

```
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
public static extern int RevokeDragDrop(UIntPtr hwnd);
```

Now, I would like to restore the drag and drop for that application. Is there any API to restore it back?

Comment: In a C# program you'd normally change the AllowDrop property to get these native functions called.  We can't tell why you want to pinvoke, if *hwnd* belongs to another process then there is no way to correctly re-enable it.  Since the IDropTarget interface reference must belong to that process.

Comment: If it is possible to enable it for an external program, wouldn't it count as a security hazard?

Answer (score 2):

You'd use the `RegisterDragDrop` function, which is how it was (likely) originally set.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ole2/nf-ole2-registerdragdrop:

> If your application can accept dropped objects during OLE drag-and-drop operations, you must call the RegisterDragDrop function. Do this whenever one of your application windows is available as a potential drop target, i.e., when the window appears unobscured on the screen.

Comment: Note that `RegisterDragDrop()` is not the only way a window can accept drops. There is also `DragAcceptFiles()`. Also note that `RegisterDragDrop()` requires an `IDropTarget` object, which you can't query from a window, so if you `RevokeDragDrop()` a window you don't own, you can't restore its `IDropTarget` correctly.

Comment: I do not own this window. RegisterDragDrop seems to just one way as it seems we cannot restore it back using RegisterDragDrop.
Looks DragAcceptFiles might be helpful. I will look into this.

Comment: It wasn't clear from the question that you don't own the window. Sorry!

Comment: I tried using      [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        public static extern void DragAcceptFiles(IntPtr hwnd, bool fAccept);     
Then from the code, I called DragAcceptFiles(handleOfThatProcess,false) but it is not blocking drag and drop file in that application.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this? Block file drag and drop and unblock it again. I know using mouse hooking can solve this but mouse hooking takes too much CPU.